# Inequality for the square of difference

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

is it true the following inequality?
$$(a-b)^2 \leq C |a^2-b^2|$$
for some $C>0$, for every $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that were true then $f(x)=x^2$ would be uniformly continuous on the whole real line, but it isn't.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false in general, otherwise you would have $(a-(-a))^2\leqslant C|a^2-(-a)^2|$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, that is $4a^2\leqslant 0$ and thus $\mathbb{R}=\{0\}$ (and they are not quite the same sets).